# Random speed in javascript count?

Tags: javascript

So I have this javascript which basically goes from 0 to 1000 at the same exact speed:

HTML:

```
<div id="value">0</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    if (start === end) return;
    var range = end - start;
    var current = start;
    var increment = end > start? 1000 : +1;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, stepTime);
}

animateValue("value", 100, 25, 5000);
```

Basically I want the counter to go up with random speed intervals.

So as it goes up, it will slow down and speed up completely random until it reaches 1000.

How do I achieve that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use `setTimeout`

Comment: Why `start` greater when `end` in `animateValue("value", 100, 25, 5000)`?

Comment: some name, it's a script that I found that first counted from 100 to 0. I changed a bit so that it would count up. And left everything unchanged. Not an expert myself, just trying to achieve a gaol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don`t understand purpose of `duration` parameter in function. That is why i used it as a max duration of one iteration.

```js
/**
* Increment value with random intervals.
* @param {string} id - Id of DOM Element.
* @param {number} start - Start counter value. Applied immediately.
* @param {number} end - End counter value.
* @duration {number} duration - Max duration of one iteration in ms.
*/
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
  let current = start;
  const obj = document.getElementById(id);
  obj.innerHTML = current; // immediately apply start value
  const setIncrOut = () => {
    let time = Math.random() * duration;
    setTimeout(function () {
      if (current < end) {
        current += 1;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        setIncrOut(time);
      }
    }, time);
  }

  setIncrOut();
}

animateValue("value", 100, 1001, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="value"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted. That will do the job for now. Is there a way to control the speed of how fast it will go up?

Comment: @r0naldinio I have updated my answer. You can control speed by change `duration` value.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot for your time @some name! I appreciated it!

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version:

```js
animate(document.querySelector(`#value`), 5, 50, 1000);

function animate(elem, start, end, maxDuration) {
  elem = elem || document.querySelector(`#value`);
    
  if (start < end) {
    elem.textContent = !elem.textContent.trim() ? start : start + 1;
    return setTimeout( () =>
      animate( elem, start + 1, end, maxDuration ), 
        Math.floor( (Math.random() * maxDuration) ) );
  }
}
```

```css
#value {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="value"></div>
```

Comment: The first number will always be skipped.

Comment: Edited, not anymore ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using setInterval, which has a static pause between iterations you could create your own asynchronous loop that pauses with variable time.

Incomplete, but something like...

```js
async function setVaryingInterval(callback, start, end, increment) {
  var step = start;
  while (step != end) {
    step += increment;
    var random = Math.random() * 3000;
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, random));
    callback(step);
  }
}

setVaryingInterval((value) => {
  // this will be executed with random delays, and the delay can be changed by adding logic to the "random" variable
  console.log(value);
}, 0, 1000, 1);
```

You will need to add logic for speeding up / slowing down, this will simply have a random delay between every interval, but should be easy enough to add if you have a vision on how it should behave.

You can paste this code in your dev tools (F12) and see the random behaviour, and tailor it to your needs.

Comment: Appreciate your time and help Frerdrik, as I'm new to javascript, I couldn't able to run the script on my own. But there's an answer already that does what I wanted. Thanks for your time again.